# How to join 4 tables in mysql with limit

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following database tables:

```
`event` ( `event_id,event_name,organizer_id` )
`event_keyword_relation` (`event_id,keyword_relation`)
`user_keyword_relation` (`user_id,keyword_id`)
`user_organizer_relation` (`user_id,organizer_id`)
```

I want to fetch `event_name` from `event`, according to same `keyword_id` in `event_keyword_relation,user_keyword_relation`
or common `organizer_id` in event and `user_organizer_relation` for a particular `user_id`, with limit

My query is:

```
SELECT e.event_name 
  FROM event e
  JOIN event_keyword_relation ekr 
    ON ekr.event_id=e.event_id 
  JOIN user_keyword_relation ukr 
    ON ekr.u_keyword_id=ukr.u_keyword_id 
  JOIN user_organizer_relation uor 
    ON  e.organizer_id = uor.organizer_id 
 WHERE ukr.user_id=11 
   AND uor.user_id=11 
 LIMIT 1,20.
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: And what is your problem?